# Does OrderedDict.items() also keeps the order preserved?

Tags: python, ordereddictionary, python-collections

Assuming that I'm using the following OrderedDict:

`order_dict = OrderedDict([("a",1), ("b",2), ("c",3)])`

At some point, I would like to get the (key,value) items and define an iterator, and start moving it once desired:

```
ordered_dict_items_iter = iter(ordered_dict.items())
...
key,val = next(ordered_dict_items_iter)
...
```

I'd like to know if `order_dict.items()` will also preserve the same order?

As I observed it seems that it does preserve the order, however I couldn't prove it.

Comment: Yes. `OrderedDict.items()` returns the items in `insertion` order

Answer (score 0):

It does. The idea of `OrderedDict` is that is behaves *exactly* as a dictionary, but internally it's a list of tuples, representing key-values pairs, so that order is preserved. All dictionary methods are replicated using this list of tuples.

Note: After python 3.7, standard dictionaries are also guaranteed to maintain insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it'll preserve the order you specify while initiliazing the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `OrderedDict.items()` will return the `items` in the order they are inserted.

If you check the [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L81) of `OrderedDict`, you can see that `items` returns `_OrderedDictItemsView`.

```
class OrderedDict(dict):
    ...
    ...
    def items(self):
        "D.items() -> a set-like object providing a view on D's items"
        return _OrderedDictItemsView(self)
```

And if you dig deep and find the [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L66) of `_OrderedDictItemsView`,

```
class _OrderedDictItemsView(_collections_abc.ItemsView):

    def __reversed__(self):
        for key in reversed(self._mapping):
            yield (key, self._mapping[key])
```

And if you go deeper to check the [_collections_abc.ItemsView](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L725), you will see that,

```
class ItemsView(MappingView, Set):
    ...
    ...
    def __iter__(self):
        for key in self._mapping:
           yield (key, self._mapping[key])
```

And further down the [MappingView](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L694), you will see,

```
class MappingView(Sized):

    __slots__ = '_mapping',

    def __init__(self, mapping):
        self._mapping = mapping
```

Now our journey has reached it's destination, and we can see that the `_mapping` is the `OrderedDict` we created and it is always in order. The `__iter__` method `ItemsView`, just iterates through each key value in the `OrderedDict`. Hence the proof :)